# VS2008 Keyboard shortcut open Code in front

Tags: visual-studio-2008, shortcut, code-behind

This is probably a total newb question but does anyone know how to make the <kbd>F7</kbd> keyboard shortcut in VS2008 open the code-in-front page in source view rather than design view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Tools, Options, HTML Designer, Start Pages, Source View.</strike>

Also, you mean Shift+F7.

---

**EDIT**: If you want to view the code-behind and the HTML source simultaneously, you'll need to drag the designer tab to the middle of the screen and create a second horizontal (or vertical) pane.

---

**EDIT**: Once you're in Design view, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> again will switch to HTML source view.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but maybe I should have been a little more explicit...what I want is to view the HTML source of the code-in-front page whilst I'm viewing the code-behind page. Thanks

Comment: If VS2008 is in HTML Source view, I can press F7 and I'm then presented with the corresponding code behind page. I then press F7 again and it takes me to the HTML page but in design view [not Source view]. What I want is the keyboard shortcut that takes me from the code-behind back to the HTML Source view and not Design View. I know this is really trivial stuff but these can save stacks of time in the long run...and will help prevent the onset of RSI

Comment: Okay - that works a treat. I was hoping for a shortcut straight to HTML source view from the code behind view. But I've been playing with this for a while now and need to move on with my life. Thanks for your help.